# $\big(\frac{G}{N}\big)^{(n)}=\frac{G^{(n)}N}{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

$G$ is a group and $N\unlhd G$ then, $\forall n\in \mathbb N, \big(\frac{G}{N}\big)^{(n)}=\frac{G^{(n)}N}{N}$

$(G/N)^{(n)}=\left \{ Nx :x\in G \right \}^{(n)}=\left \{ Nx^{n} :x\in G \right \}$ but from here I couldn't reach $G^{(n)}N/N$ part.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $\varphi: G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism then $\varphi(G')=H'$. This is easy to check from the definitions, so I'll leave it to you. Then by induction it follows that $\varphi(G^{(n)})=H^{(n)}$.

So in particular if we take $\pi: G\to G/N$ to be the canonical homomorphism then:

$(G/N)^{(n)}=[\pi(G)]^{(n)}=\pi(G^{(n)})=G^{(n)}N/N$

Comment: I don’t get $\pi(G^{(n)})=G^{(n)}N/N$ part. Why we get $N/N$ ?

Comment: It's not $N/N$, it's $G^{(n)}N/N$, or as you called it $\frac{G^{(n)}N}{N}$. This is the image of $G^{(n)}$ under $\pi$, as you can check.